# Nesting Select Case by branching cases, maybe?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub that I need to run on a bunch of sheets in my workbook. Right now I'm using Select Case to modify variables depending on which sheet I'm in. Each sheet has at least one unique instance of a variable, but some share the same instance of a variable.

For instance, for both `Sheet1` & `Sheet2`, `variable1 = A` and `variable2 = B`. But for `Sheet1`, `variable3 = "Toast"` & `variable4 = 14578`, and for `Sheet2`, `variable3 = "Batman'` and `variable4 = "4/27/1982"`. For `Sheet3`, `variable1 = 47`, `variable2 = "Triangle"`, `variable3 = "Robin"`, `variable4 = X`.

This is what I want to do.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
           With ws
              variable1 = A
              variable2 = B
              Select Case ???? 'not sure what goes here
                   Case "Sheet1"
                      With ws
                          variable3 = "Toast"
                          variable4 = 14578
                          Call sub analyze(variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4)
                      End With
                   Case "Sheet2"
                      With ws
                          variable3 = "Batman"
                          variable4 = "4/27/1982"
                          Call sub analyze(variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4)
                      End With
              End Select
           End With
        Case "Sheet 3"
           With ws
             variable1 = 47
             variable2 = "Triangle"
             variable3 = "Robin"
             variable4 = X
             Call sub analyze(variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4)
    End Select
Next
```

I hope what I'm trying to do makes sense. If that's possible, I don't know what's that second case I'm trying to select. Can I just `Select Case ws.Name` again? Do I need a variable? Now that I'm looking at it, I think I need another `For Each` loop. But `For Each` what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be easiest just to treat each sheet separately and set all four variables for each sheet regardless if they duplicate.

Then call the sub after the select case not in it.  And as @Ethan pointed out we would want to add a Boolean to ensure the sub is called only if the sheet matches in the Select Case.

We also do the With on the outside of everything so it is done only once.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4
Dim doIt as Boolean
doIt = False
For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
        Select Case .Name
            Case "Sheet1"
                variable1 = a
                variable2 = B
                variable3 = "Toast"
                variable4 = 14578
                doIt = True
            Case "Sheet2"
                variable1 = a
                variable2 = B
                variable3 = "Batman"
                variable4 = "4/27/1982"
                doIt = True
            Case "Sheet 3"
                 variable1 = 47
                 variable2 = "Triangle"
                 variable3 = "Robin"
                 variable4 = x
                doIt = True
        End Select
        If doIt then Call sub analyze(variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4)
    End With
Next ws
```

Comment: He might need an if statement around the call to analyze(), in case sheet 4 should be ignored

Comment: @Ethan good catch, added a boolean to test if one of the sheets or not.

Comment: @Scott Craner Thanks for the tips about where to place the `call` and `With`. That will definitely clean it up some. And I have started the way you suggest, but there are actually 12 variables and 9 sheets to analyze. The sheets themselves represent various customers we do business with and the idea was to 1) clean up the code and 2) create less work for when new customers are added in the future, especially since some will always share instances of variables. So is it possible to do it the way I'm thinking?

Comment: @BrettRussellAce I think that a rabbit hole you do not want to go down.  The readability and maintenance would be a nightmare.  Especially if later down the line one of the shared variables diverges, taking it apart would be horrendous.  This is a matter of copy paste then change the values.  It really is not that hard to write and will be much easier to maintain.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ok, but I am curious now. In the code I posted, what would it look like? I'm just starting to use `Select Case` and I'm trying to understand how that nesting would work.

Comment: you would just do another `Select Case ws.Name` again.